# How to create a pdf for a chatbot?

Tags: laravel, bots

I want to create a pdf from my chatbot in telegram, I am using botman studio 
that integrates laravel.

BotMan is a framework agnostic PHP library that is designed to simplify the task of developing innovative bots for multiple messaging platforms, including Slack, Telegram, Microsoft Bot Framework, Nexmo, HipChat, Facebook Messenger, WeChat and many more.

Investigate the library dompdf is relatively easy to use when it comes to html, but I want to fill it with the functions of the bot, instead of returning to a view, return to the API.

```
private function searchCompatibility()
  {

    $detalles = DB::table('detalle_cable')->join('cable', 'cable.id', '=', 'detalle_cable.idcable')
    ->join('modelo', 'modelo.id', '=', 'detalle_cable.idmodelo')
    ->join('marca','marca.id','=','modelo.idmarca')
    ->where('modelo.description','=', $this->valueModel)
    ->where('marca.id','=', $this->valueBrand)
    ->select('cable.description as ca')
    ->groupBy('ca')
    ->get();

    $detalles2 = DB::table('conector_detalle')
    ->join('conector', 'conector.id', '=', 'conector_detalle.idconec')
    ->join('modelo', 'modelo.id', '=', 'conector_detalle.idmodelo')
    ->join('marca','marca.id','=','modelo.idmarca')
    ->where('modelo.description','=', $this->valueModel)
    ->where('marca.id','=', $this->valueBrand)
    ->select('conector.descripcion as co')
    ->groupBy('co')
    ->get();

    $detalles3 = DB::table('detalle_configuracion')
    ->join('configuracion', 'configuracion.id', '=', 'detalle_configuracion.idconf')
    ->join('modelo', 'modelo.id', '=', 'detalle_configuracion.idmodelo')
    ->join('marca','marca.id','=','modelo.idmarca')
    ->where('modelo.description','=', $this->valueModel)
    ->where('marca.id','=', $this->valueBrand)
    ->select('configuracion.descripcion as con')
    ->groupBy('con')
    ->get();

    $this->say('Compatibilidad para '.$this->valueModel.':');
    $this->say('Conector: ');

    foreach ($detalles2 as $key => $detalle) {
       $this->say(''.$detalle->co);
     }

     $this->say('Cable: ');

      foreach ($detalles as $key => $deta) {
       $this->say(''.$deta->ca);
     }
  $this->say('Configuracion: ');

  foreach ($detalles3 as $key => $detal) {
       $this->say(''.$detal->con);
     }
    $this->continuar();
  }
```

For example, this code fragment found in App / Conversations.php

How can I pass it to the pdf?

Comment: Do you want to create pdf and send back to user?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that Rohan